# Reading deep json hierarchy in PowerBI

Tags: json, powerbi

My goal is to have a datasource like this

[image: target table]

From a json file similar to this (in reality it is a geojson file with more properties, but this is the structure):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 1,
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": ".."
        },
        "properties": {
            "ProjectNr": "001",
            "ProjectName": "Proj1"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 2,
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": ".."
        },
        "properties": {
            "ProjectNr": "002",
            "ProjectName": "Proj2"
        }
    }
]
```

}

So the steps is to create a table from the *features* property, but get the column names and actual rows from the *properties* object nested a level deeper.

I can get a table with a single row with these steps in the query editor:

[image: steps taken for single row table]

This is shown in the advanced editor as:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents(".\projekter.api.geojson")),
    features = Source[features],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(features, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    Column1 = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Column1],
    properties = Column1[properties],
    #"Converted to Table1" = Record.ToTable(properties),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table1"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ProjektNr", type text}, {"ProjektNavn", type text}, {"ProjektBeskrivelse", type text}, {"AnlaegsBeloeb", Int64.Type}, {"BudgetUdgift", Int64.Type}, {"BudgetIndtaegt", Int64.Type}, {"BudgetAar", Int64.Type}, {"ProjektlederNavn", type text}, {"ForventetAnlaegStart", type datetime}, {"ForventetAnlaegSlut", type datetime}, {"ForventetProjekteringStart", type datetime}, {"ForventetProjekteringSlut", type datetime}, {"ProjektfaseBetegnelse", type text}, {"ProjektkategoriBetegnelse", type text}, {"ProjekttypeBetegnelse", type text}, {"StrategiBetegnelse", type text}, {"HjemmesideLink", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

This entails creating a table from the features, then navigating into the first record and mangling the structure to get the proper layout, but I can't figure out how to repeat a similar process for each row, or if I am barking up the wrong tree on this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a solution for the details rows, you can convert the entire code into a function. This function can then be recalled on every line of the table.

Creating a function. 
Consider you have the following query (advanced editor):

```
let

       Source = Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Month(InDate)),2,"0") &

       "/" & Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Day(InDate)),2,"0") & "/"

       &Text.From(Date.Year(InDate))

in

      Source

in

      FormatDate
```

you can create a function, and give parameters. (in this exemple indate)

just add another let and In statement around your previous code.

```
let

     FormatDate = (InDate as date) =>
let    
       Source = Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Month(InDate)),2,"0") &

       "/" & Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Day(InDate)),2,"0") & "/"

       &Text.From(Date.Year(InDate))

in

      Source
```

Recalling this function can be done by adding a custom column.

Comment: I added the code as shown in the advanced editor to the question. Can you explain using that code as example?